Why do sex toy companies label their products as Novelty or 'External Use' while clearly marketing them as otherwise?
Many sex toys are sold as novelty or recommended for external usage. Such as this glow in the dark set. Likewise, I recently purchased a Jimmy Jane toy and despite it being for internal use and clearly stating on the back "your g-spot and clitoris will be simultaneously sent [...]", it states on the bottom:

Caution: This massager is for therapeutic purposes and is recommended
for external use only. Prolonged and frequent use is not advised or
recommended., as these items are sold for novelty purposes only. This
massager is intended for adult use only.".

Why do companies put this on their packages? Is it to somehow skirt safety laws? Does it mean their products are unsafe?

I have always understood "external use" to mean it is not supposed to go through your digestive tract or bloodstream, but applied to your body where you can reach... I am no medical professional, but I think your premise might be wrong. Using a "massager" where you can reach is external (compared to swallowing it and dissolving it in your stomach acid and having parts of it absorbed through your digestive process, or melting it into goo and injecting it with a syringe).

While you are using it with a part of the body that has mucous membranes, it's not meant to transcend that boundary and do something in your body. It's use is purely external.

(sorry for the long comment, this is not an answer, because it has nothing to do with the law or the question you asked, just making you aware that the premise might not be what you think it is)

External to what?  'for external use only': for a product that is designed to be used  solely in one area ('Jimmy Jane toy' for the anal area) then external is outside of that area (i.e. not for use inside your intestine).

I would guess that this is one of those things which hasn't been tested in court, and may or may not have legal effect, but which manufacturers see no downside to writing on their packaging or instruction leaflets.

The downside is that people become conditioned to ignore safety warnings because so many are an insult to common sense.

@MichaelHall This is my concern, because obviously this is going inside and is for internal use. It would be weird if it wasn't and im not keeping it as a novelty in the term of decoration or gag gift. It is meant to be used and it seems silly they would add these warnings.

@user2231142 I have seen warnings about what you should and should not microwave. I think in a society where you have to tell people to not microwave other living beings, nothing is too silly to print as a warning onto a thing. I have literally seen a hammer that says "does not float". I am sure there are specialized tools that do float, but I would have thought that "hammer does not float in water" could be seen as a universal default everyone just assumes. I guess not.

My guess would be that the "not for internal use" disclaimer is an attempt to evade product liability/personal injury claims. A personal injury claim from a faulty product injuring a person's genitalia could easily stretch into the millions of dollars. As a comment noted, I'm not aware of this being tested in court, and don't have time to fully research, but it doesn't hurt the vendor to try.
Also, calling it novelty should help it to avoid the FDA definition of a medical device:

Per Section 201(h)(1) of the Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act, a device
is: An instrument, apparatus, implement, machine, contrivance,
implant, in vitro reagent, or other similar or related article,
including a component part, or accessory which is:
(A) recognized in the official National Formulary, or the United
States Pharmacopoeia, or any supplement to them,
(B) intended for use
in the diagnosis of disease or other conditions, or in the cure,
mitigation, treatment, or prevention of disease, in man or other
animals, or
(C) intended to affect the structure or any function of
the body of man or other animals, and which does not achieve its
primary intended purposes through chemical action within or on the
body of man or other animals and which is not dependent upon being
metabolized for the achievement of its primary intended purposes. The
term "device" does not include software functions excluded pursuant to
section 520(o).


Given that the definition you quoted doesn't mention anything about "internal use", why would that help? Obviously plenty of medical devices aren't intended for internal use.

@Sneftel You are right, I meant to reference the "novelty" aspect, particularly with respect to (C) in medical devices. That section is very broadly worded, and could easily apply to a very wide variety of products.

Given that the definition you quoted makes no specific exceptions for "novelties", why would that help? Why would it not simply state that the device is "not intended for use in the diagnosis of disease... &c" as things like herbal supplements are labeled?

My understanding has always been not to be consumed or swallowed.  It is normally used for medicines.  For physical objects, I would assume that putting in your ear, nose, mouth etc is still external use.  These areas are open to air.
Definitions of external use
From cambridge dictionary

for external use
intended to be used only on the outside of the body, and not to be eaten or put inside the body:

This cream is for external use only.
The oil is generally considered safe for external use.


From Collins dictionary

for external use
phrase
If medicine is for external use, it is intended to be used only on the outside of your body, and not to be eaten or drunk.


For a product that is designed to be used  solely inside the body, then it should be obvious that this dictionary definition does not apply. Sorry, but this is a nonsence answer.

No. You can find medicines labeled "FOR EXTERNAL USE ONLY. NOT FOR INTRAVAGINAL OR OPHTHALMIC USE."

Would the novelty warnings perhaps just be a reference to the idea that it is a toy utilized for personal enjoyment and not a tool utilized in a medical capacity?

Perhaps, the internal use warning is so that folks do not insert it beyond the base or swallow? Both seem really hard to do.
